# Direct someone to the OTA updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Basically I am trying to put a button in my app which will warn the user if they are running an iOS version with known issues. When pressed it directs them to the OTA updates part of settings. Is this possible?

I have the code do detect if the user is using an old iOS version, however, I'm not quite sure how to switch to the settings. Does anybody have any code I can use? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you app doesn't work on lower iOS versions then you should block them from installing your app to start with. Some users might not have upgraded due to hardware limits.

Comment: The application works on older versions. It is a matter of apple's decision to give developers no where to store their information on 5.0. Versions previous to 5.0 work and versions after 5.0 work. Just because you can't see a practical use for it doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create a special prefs link. Check out this tutorial: [No jailbreak necessary: How to quickly access iOS settings on your iPad, iPhone or iPod](http://holgr.com/blog/2011/11/no-jailbreak-necessary-how-to-quickly-access-ios-settings-on-your-ipad-iphone-or-ipod/)

> prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK

Comment: Yes. But there's no OTA before iOS 5

Comment: Yes, My point was to the OP that this isn't so useful, because there's only one OS that could use this feature and as its the latest one, it likely isn't the one the app has problems with

Comment: I'll give it a try in a little bit and let you know if it works.

Comment: Probably should have put it under the question.